# Error in Angular $http.get method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, api

I want to retrive the data using REST api response and display in my html page. Here is the code I have written so far. Can anyone help me in writing the correct code as I am new to use web services.

When I insert into database using rest API it is inserted. I want the data that is inserted into the database through the rest API response and I want to display the same result on the webpage.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>AngularJS File Upoad Example with $http and FormData</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="name" ng-model="contact.name"></td>
  <td><input type="email" ng-model="contact.username"></td>
  <td><input type="password" ng-model="contact.password"></td>
  <td><button ng-click="addContact()">Sign In</button></td>
  <td><button ng-click="viewContact()">view</button></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 myApp.controller('MyController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.addContact = function(){
        console.log($scope.contact);
        $http.post('http://localhost:8085/useraccount/register/doregister',$scope.contact);
    };
    $scope.viewContact = function(){
     console.log($scope.contact);
     $http.get('http://localhost:8085/useraccount/register/doselect',$scope.contact);
    };
 }]);
 
</script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$http.get` incorrectly.

```
$scope.viewContact = function(){
    console.log($scope.contact);
    $http.get('http://localhost:8085/useraccount/register/doselect')
      .then(function(response) { 
        $scope.contact = response;
      });
};
```

`$http.get` returns a promise and you will have to use `.then` to access the API response.